# PHP Laravel Dusk Uses American Date Time Format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

In my site, there's a form with a datetime. When I open the site, the datetime format is this:

[wanted datetime format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Gzz.png)

Notice the last two dashes. These are for AM or PM, not used in the European date format.

However Laravel Dusk shows this field this way:

[datetime format Laravel Dusk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfTE3.png)

Filling in the form thus fails, because the American datetime format is used where the European datetime format should be used.
I have tried a datetime converter, which didn't work.

Is there any way to configure Laravel Dusk to see datetime fields in the European fashion?

Comment: What does your test look like?

Answer (score 0):

What ever the date format is coming but if you wan to change the date format as your desired date format then you can try following solution,

```
function convertDateFormat ($date) 
{ 
    // convert date and time to seconds 
    $sec = strtotime($date); 

    // convert seconds into a specific format 
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i", $sec); 

    // append seconds to the date and time 
    $date = $date . ":00"; 

    // print final date and time 
    echo $date; 
} 

// Driver code 
$date = "01/01/2019 10:00 AM"; 
convertDateFormat ($date);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The form field still requires the date and time with the AM/PM at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by configuring the ChromeDriver language.